# Drive Genius says: "Invalid catalog btree reverse link in node" is this fixable?

Tags: macos, mac, troubleshooting, filesystems

No obvious problems with my Mac OS X 10.5 system, but Drive Genius 1.5.1 says: "Invalid catalog btree reverse link in node" when doing a "Verify"

The "repair" and "rebuild" options fail.

I did some googling, and the consensus as:

1. Drive Genius is slightly better than Disk Warrior
2. This problem is likely not fixable.

My assumed solution is that I should do a full backup and re-format.

Comment: You tried Disk Utility too didn't you?
Sometimes one tool works where another won't.

Answer (score 2):

It can be fixed, but that fix may destroy some data. DiskWarrior's your best bet for this type of corruption.

Answer (score 1):

I'd give DiskWarrior a try first, if you can lay your hands on it.
I've had really good results with it, not tried Drive Genius but from my understanding it's more of an all purpose suite whereas DiskWarrior does directory structures fixes and that's it.

If that fails, I'd reboot with the system disks in the drive, hold down 'd' and run an extended hardware test, to check your RAM/ HD in particular or use Tech Tools Deluxe if you have the Applecare although the AEHT is best and free.

If the hardware gets the all clear then backup and re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try the Disk Utility from the Install DVD? Because that doesn't reside on the disk you are using, it may be able to fix more 'resilient' problems. I have found that sometimes this is the solution, though it is very well possible your install is screwed.